# Keras Custom Loss Function using with confusion matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I was trying to create a custom loss function in Keras for a binary classification problem based on a confusion matrix. More precisely, the following equation should be minimized: `

Min: 10xFalsePositive + 500xFalse Negative

I wrote the following custom loss function:

```
def custom_loss_func(y_train, y_pred):
    cm=metrics.confusion_matrix(y_train,y_pred)
    cm1 = pd.DataFrame(cm.reshape((1,4)), columns=['TN', 'FP', 'FN', 'TP'])
    cm1 = cm1.fillna(0)
    TC= 10*cm1.FP + 500*cm1.FN
    return float (TC)

# Compiling the ANN
ann.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = my_loss_fn, metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fitting the ANN to the Training set
ann.fit(x_train,y_train,batch_size=32,epochs = 50, class_weight= class_weights)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic tf.Tensor (my_loss_fn/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. 
This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported.
```

I also tried a native Tensorflow implementation:

```
def my_loss_fn(y_train, y_pred):
    FP = tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives()
    FP.update_state(y_train, y_pred)
    FP=m.result().numpy()

    FN = tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives()
    FN.update_state(y_train, y_pred)
    FN=n.result().numpy()

    # Converted as Keras Tensors
    FP = tf.Variable(m)
    FN = tf.Variable(n)

    loss = 500*FN + 10*FP

    return loss
```

This one gave me the follwing error:

```
ValueError(f"No gradients provided for any variable: {variable}. "

 f"Provided `grads_and_vars` is {grads_and_vars}.")
  if vars_with_empty_grads:
 logging.warning(
 ("Gradients do not exist for variables %s when minimizing the loss. "
 "If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss`"
 "argument?"),
 ([v.name for v in vars_with_empty_grads]))
```

Could anyone give me some help on this problem?

Comment: Try something with native tf ops https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix

Comment: thanks for the hint. Unfortunately it didn't work either. I have adjusted the post

Comment: Doing this makes no sense as FN and FP are not differentiable.

Comment: Yes, that will be the problem.
Do you have an idea how I can still integrate the minimization of my cost function into the optimization of my neural network?